# Compute the determinant of this matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let A = $\begin{bmatrix}r_1 & r_2 & r_3 & r_4 & r_5\end{bmatrix}^T$ have rows **$r_1$**, **$r_2$**, **$r_3$**, **$r_4$**, **$r_5$** $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^5$.  Assume det(A) = -3.

Compute

det $\begin{bmatrix}2r_1 + 3r_2 + 4r_3 + 4r_4\\ r_1 + 2r_2\\ r_2+3r_3\\r_3+4r_4\\r_1\end{bmatrix}$ and justify your answer.

*(the part before this was the same thing but with this matrix)*

det $\begin{bmatrix}5r_1 + 5r_2 + 5r_3 + 5r_4 + 5r_5\\ 4r_1 + 4r_2 + 4r_3 + 4r_4\\ r_1\\2r_1+2r_2\\3r_1+3r_2+3r_3\end{bmatrix}$

and I think I figured this one out (you just Gauss-Jordan it and it ends up being equal to A so it's just -3)

But my main confusion is with the first matrix, because even with Gauss-Jordan it doesn't equal A so how can I even find the determinant because it's not a square matrix.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: $r_1, r_2$, $r_3$, $r_4$, and $r_5\in\mathbb R^5$ are *rows* of the matrix; there are $5$ rows, each with $5$ components, so it's square

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that the two matrices under consideration can be written as $M_1A$ and $M_2A$ respectively, where
$$
M_1 = 
\pmatrix{2&3&4&4&0\\ 1&2&0&0&0\\ 0&1&3&0&0\\0&0&1&4&0\\1&0&0&0&0}, \quad
M_2 = 
\pmatrix{
5&5&5&5&5\\ 4&4&4&4&0\\ 1&0&0&0&0\\2&2&0&0&0\\3&3&3&0&0
}.
$$

Comment: can they? because the matrix itself is not 5x5, it's 5x1...

Comment: @grace Yes. Recall that two matrices can be multiplied as long as the "inner dimensions" agree. In this case, we're multiplying a $5 \times \color{red}{5}$ and a $\color{red}{5} \times 5$ matrix.

Comment: @grace The fact that pretending that $A$ is a column vector still gives you the correct answer is an example of [block-matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_multiplication).

Comment: Okay, but when I do that I get a completely different answer for the the other matrix (the one with 5's, 4's, 3's, 2's, and 1's).  When I do it the way you suggest I get -120 but when I do it the way I initially did it I get -3, which is the same determinant as matrix A.

Comment: The correct answer is that the determinant of your second matrix is equal to $\det(M_2)\cdot \det(A) = -120 \cdot -3 = 360$. It seems that whatever you initially did is incorrect.

Comment: Okay but I'm looking in my textbook at a very similar problem and the correct answer is also the determinant of the original column. here's what I'm talking about: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/182bZ5icnsWkZ8TW_I4JUq7-TSkUwakqF?usp=sharing

Comment: @grace The fact that the rows are also being multiplied by $2,3,4,5$ results in our difference in the resulting determinants.

Comment: but I'm saying if you do it the way you're suggesting you get a determinant of 1, not 8.

Comment: @grace You do not get that. With the method I'm suggesting: $A$ has determinant $8$, and the matrix we want the determinant of is $MA$ for the "coefficient matrix" $M$. As you found, $\det(M) = 1$. It follows that the determinant you're looking for is 
$$
\det(MA) = \det(M)\det(A) = 1 \cdot 8 = 8.
$$

Comment: ...oh.  Okay, that makes sense, I thought you were just using the coefficient matrix and that was all.. I'm sorry, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1:** What happens to new matrix if you do $R_1 \to R_1 - R_2 - R_3 -R_4 -R_5$ where $R$ represents the rows of the matrix in part (i).

**Hint 2:** The answer for the determinant is zero.

Comment: but there is no r5 component in the first matrix, if that's what you mean (?)

Comment: By $R_5$ I meant 5th row of the matrix in part(i). That is $R_5$ is actually $r_1$.

Comment: when you subtract all rows from R1 then it becomes 0.  but we still have rows 2-5, do we do the same to them?

Comment: If one row becomes zero the determinant vanishes. The easiest way to see this is by computing the determinant via the cofactor expansion.

Comment: ah okay, thank you!